# Better and correct way of quering with multiple condtion?

Tags: entity-framework

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin,Manager")]
public class PermissionController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<permission> Get()
    {
        using (var mydb = new ModelContainer())
        {
            if(User.IsInRole("Admin")){
                return mydb.permissionSet.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                //////Work
                return mydb.permissionSet.Where(x=>x.name!="Admin").ToList().Where(x=>x.name!="Coder").ToList().Where(x=>x.name!="Tester").ToList();
                //////Not work
                return from a in mydb.permissionSet where a.name!="Admin" && a.name!="Manager" && a.name!="Coder" && a.name != "Tester" select a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think there are two ways of return the correct result, the first way above will work, but seems weird and I think it will query many times. The second way seems better way, but not work.

Comment: "Not work" is vague -- exception? empty result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put them all in the same where clause line, ie.

```
return mydb.permissionSet.Where(x=>x.name!="Admin" & x.name!="Coder" & x.name!="Tester").ToList();
```

btw, I dont think it re-queries in the way you did it first, it just filters the resulting list, but there may be a bit of overhead in recreating the list each time after the filter, ie. I think

```
 return db.permissionSet.Where(x=>x.name!="Admin").Where(x=>x.name!="Coder").Where(x=>x.name!="Tester").ToList();
```

should be equally efficient to the consolidated where clause above

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ you are building a *query*. Calling ToList() on such a query will force the query to execute and return the results. Your first option will build the query and return the results. Your second option returns the query. That is the difference.

```
mydb.permissionSet.Where(x=>x.name!="Admin").ToList().Where(x=>x.name!="Coder").ToList().Where(x=>x.name!="Tester").ToList();
```

Can be broken up as this:

```
var qryNoAdmin = mydb.permissionSet.Where(x=>x.name!="Admin");
var permissionSetNoAdmins = qryNoAdmin.ToList();
var qryNoAdminNoCoder = permissionSetNoAdmins.Where(x=>x.name!="Coder");
var permissionSetNoAdminsNoCoders = qryNoAdminNoCoder.ToList();
var qryNoAdminNoCoderNoTester = permissionSetNoAdminsNoCoders .Where(x=>x.name!="Tester");
var permissionSetNoAdminsNoCodersNoTesters = qryNoAdminNoCoderNoTester.ToList();
return permissionSetNoAdminsNoCodersNoTesters;
```

If that looks inefficient to you... Yes it is. Look at @user1778606 suggestion to make it more efficient.

Now your second option only returns the query. If you call ToList() on that, the query will be executed and you get the results.

```
var qryNoAdminNoCoderNoTester = from a in mydb.permissionSet where a.name!="Admin" && a.name!="Manager" && a.name!="Coder" && a.name != "Tester" select a;
var permissionSetNoAdminsNoCodersNoTesters = qryNoAdminNoCoderNoTester.ToList();
return permissionSetNoAdminsNoCodersNoTesters;
```

Please note I didn't test this code. There might be typos.

Suggested reading: [Introduction to LINQ Queries (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx%20Introduction%20to%20LINQ%20Queries%20%28C#%29)